# I am unable to login

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my app controller

**Controller:-**

```
*App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');*

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {
 //public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
     public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'restaurants',
                'action' => 'index'


            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                  'username' => 'my_user_model_username_field', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                  'password' => 'my_user_model_password_field'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                )
            )
            )
        ),
        'Search.Prg' => array(
        'commonProcess' => array('paramType' => 'named'),
        'presetForm' => array('paramType' => 'named')
  )

    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view','logout');
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Member')
);
    }
}
```

**This is my user controller**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
    }
    public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

    public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        // Prior to 2.5 use
        // $this->request->onlyAllow('post');

        $this->request->allowMethod('post');

        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

}
```

My password is getting encrypted and stored in the database,however I am not able to log I get a message saying invalid password.
I am not able to undersstand why this is happening I have also changed users model. [image]

Comment: What does the `redirectUrl()` function do? Is that defined correctly? Try and put a simple `echo` statement or do this `if ($this->Auth->login()) {
             $this->Session->setFlash(__('Success!!'));
        }` and put the other `setFlash` statement in the `else` block. I'm assuming you're using the default code provided by the cakephp cookbook so there are no syntax errors.

Comment: ya I used cake php cook book redirect i guess it will direct it to the page intended...I am new to this and not sure sorry :(....I tried urif statement inside usercontroller but didnt work :(

Comment: What is your table name which is used to authorize the user? It should be members as per AppController file.

Comment: Ya my table name is user....now I have changed it to 'User' but I still get a message saying invalid password

Answer (score 0):

You define userModel in auth component. Like it

```
'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'restaurants',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        /* 'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?', */
        'authError' => '',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'userModel' => 'Member'
            )
        )
    )

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view','logout');
}
```

Comment: Ya that is my model :(

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. You can set some actions in beforeFilter function in AppController

Now your AppController look like this

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

var $components =   array('Email', 'Security', 'RequestHandler', 'Session', 'Auth');

function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback  =   '__securityError';  
    if(!empty($this->params['admin']) && $this->params['admin'] ==  1)
    {
        $this->Auth->loginAction    =   array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect  =   array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'admin_index');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect =   array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'fields' => array('username' => 'username'),
            // 'scope' =>array('User.published = "1"')
            )
        );
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
        $this->Auth->allow('login', 'admin_forgot_password');
        $this->layout   =   'admin';          
    }
}
```

Step 2. Now create function __securityError() in AppController.

```
function __securityError()
{

}
```

Step 3. Login function in UsersController

```
function admin_login()
{    
    if($this->Auth->user())
    {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Pages', 'action'=>'index'));
    }   
    if(!empty($this->request->data))
    {       
       $this->{$this->pageModel}->set($this->data); 
       if($this->{$this->pageModel}->validates())
       {
          if($this->Auth->login())
          {
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Pages', 'actin'=>'index'));
          }
         else if(!empty($this->request->data))
          {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Login Details.');
          }
       }
       else{
          $errors = $this->{$this->pageModel}->validationErrors;
          $this->set('errors',$errors);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I am really new to php and I tried reffering the web for handling security errors but I was not sucessful... I do not know what to fill in this function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback  =   '__securityError';

Answer (score 0):

Change your component call to look like the one below.

public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'restaurants',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
        ),
        'Search.Prg' => array(
        'commonProcess' => array('paramType' => 'named'),
        'presetForm' => array('paramType' => 'named')
  )

```
);
```

I believe you where telling CakePHP to authenticate the fields:

'username' => 'my_user_model_username_field'
'password' => 'my_user_model_password_field'

Since you have not entered the name of your fields here I think CakePHP is looking for the wrong field names to validate against.

Hopefulyl this helps